# Array to drop down list value not displayed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to display an array in select option drop down list

```js
var data =  [
      { 
       "batch_number": "WJ0771104"
      },
      { 
       "batch_number": "WJ0771104"
      },
      { 
       "batch_number": "WJ0771104"
      }
    ];
var select = document.getElementById("rec_mode");
for(index in data) {
 console.log(index);
  select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(data[index], index);
}
```

```html
<select id="rec_mode"></select>
```

but i get the list with empty values inside. i can see drop down has expanded but no value inside.
any thing im doing wrong here

Comment: May we know what does this print you on console? (what is the value of index).. And also, in this context what is "data" and what is "myobject" ?

Comment: data is the given array on top. the ajax response.

Comment: There is no JSON in this question. I'd suggest you look up what [JSON actually is](https://www.json.org/)

Comment: Then why you use `myobject[index]` instead of `data[index].batch_numer` if you want to show the `batch_number` value of each item in the array?

Comment: this code won't run, what is `myobject`? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: i used this select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(data[index].batch_number, index); it worked thanks

Comment: I'd also suggest you look at your `for...in...` syntax, it [isn't doing what you think it's doing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/542251)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to get your result

```js
var data =[
  { 
   "batch_number": "WJ0771104"
  },
  { 
   "batch_number": "WJ0771104"
  },
  { 
   "batch_number": "WJ0771104"
  }
];
var select = document.getElementById("rec_mode");
for(index in data) {
console.log(index);
console.log(data[index].batch_number);
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(data[index].batch_number, index);
}
```

```html
<select id="rec_mode"></select>
```

Comment: `I am trying to get your result` is not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand what you want to say

Comment: I meant using only code with no explanations is not a good answer, after all the purposse of answering is to provide helpful insights for people and not just earn rep.

Comment: Ok, Next time i will remember this.

Comment: @chŝdk hi what if i wan to add select all to the drop down list?

Comment: @kevin What do you mean? Sorry I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for each loop on the data array instead.

Here try this.

```js
var data = [{
    "batch_number": "WJ0771104"
  }, {
    "batch_number": "WJ0771104"
  },
  {
    "batch_number": "WJ0771104"
  }
]
var select = document.getElementById("rec_mode");
data.forEach((doc) => {
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = opt.text = doc["batch_number"];
  select.add(opt);
})
```

```html
<select id="rec_mode"></select>
```

Comment: hi what if i wan to add select all to the drop down list?